# Cannot compile with error, not sure what to do

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
I am Getting error message as follows...
```

"2014-01-28 21:17:56.878 Higher or Lower 2[5869:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key enterButoonOut.'
*** First throw call stack:"

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Higher or Lower 2
//
//  Created by Michael Goedken on 1/27/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Michael Goedken. All rights reserved.
//
/
//  Created by Michael Goedken on 1/27/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Michael Goedken. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

int answer = 0;
int guess = 0;
int turn = 0;
BOOL timeStarted = NO;


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (IBAction)enterButton:(id)sender {
    NSString *input = _labelGuess.text;
    guess = [input intValue];
    _previousLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",guess];
    _labelGuess.text=@"";
    turn++;
    _guessesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",turn];

    if (timeStarted == NO){
        seconds = 0;
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.001 target:self      

selector:@selector(countUp) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    timeStarted = YES;


    if (guess < 1 || guess > 100){
        _correct.hidden = YES;
        _lower.hidden = YES;
        _higher.hidden = YES;
        _chooseNumber.hidden = YES;
        _outOfRange.hidden = NO;
    }
    else if (guess > answer) {
        _lower.hidden = NO;
        _higher.hidden = YES;
        _chooseNumber.hidden = YES;
        _correct.hidden = YES;
        _outOfRange.hidden = YES;

    }
    else if (guess < answer) {
        _lower.hidden = YES;
        _higher.hidden = NO;
        _chooseNumber.hidden = YES;
        _correct.hidden = YES;
        _outOfRange.hidden = YES;

    }
    else {
        _correct.hidden = NO;
        _lower.hidden = YES;
        _higher.hidden = YES;
        _chooseNumber.hidden = YES;
        _outOfRange.hidden = YES;
        [timer invalidate];
        _nextButtonOut.hidden = NO;
        _enterButtonOut.hidden = YES;
        _labelGuess.hidden = YES;

    }
}




-(void) countUp {
    milliSeconds ++;
    seconds = milliSeconds / 1000;
    minutes = seconds / 60;
    remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    remainingMilliSeconds = milliSeconds % 1000;
    if (minutes > 0) {
         _timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%.2d", minutes, remainingSeconds];
    }
    else {
        _timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%.2d.%.3d", minutes,           

remainingSeconds, remainingMilliSeconds];
    }
}




- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [_labelGuess resignFirstResponder];

}




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _labelGuess.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    _higher.hidden = YES;
    _lower.hidden = YES;
    _correct.hidden = YES;
    _outOfRange.hidden = YES;
    answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;
    _nextButtonOut.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"Answer %i", answer);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
} 






- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
} 


- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender {
    _correct.hidden = YES;
    _lower.hidden = YES;
    _higher.hidden = YES;
    _chooseNumber.hidden = YES;enter code here
    _outOfRange.hidden = YES;
    _labelGuess.hidden = YES;
    _guessesLabel.hidden = YES;
    _previousLabel.hidden = YES;
    _timerLabel.hidden = YES;
    _nextButtonOut.hidden = YES;
    _enterButtonOut.hidden = YES;
    _background.hidden = YES;
    _guesses.hidden = YES;
    _previous.hidden = YES;

}
@end










//
//  ViewController.h
//  Higher or Lower 2
//
//  Created by Michael Goedken on 1/27/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Michael Goedken. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSTimer *timer;
    int seconds;
    int minutes;
    int remainingSeconds;
    int milliSeconds;
    int remainingMilliSeconds;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *chooseNumber;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *labelGuess;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *higher;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *lower;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *correct;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *outOfRange;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *previousLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nextButtonOut;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *enterButtonOut;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *background;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *previous;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *guessesLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *guesses;


- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)enterButton:(id)sender;




@end
```

Comment: `enterButoonOut` -- Did you misspell "Button", i.e. should this be `enterButtonOut`?

Comment: Not sure why it is saying that I foxed all them..

Comment: "for the key enterButoonOut" -- That's saying that somewhere (in a storyboard or XIB file) you misspelled "enterButtonOut".

Comment: And that's not a compile error, it's a runtime error.

Comment: Everything in storyboard is spelled right but i did get this error after I changed it, but i am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally get this error message when one of a few things happens.

1) I have misspelled the value for segue.identifier as I'm about to segue to another module (not sure this applies in your case, but that is where it always gets me).
2) If you make changes to a storyboard, then go delete the value in code, the connection does not get eliminated in your storyboard and you have to manually go in and delete the link from within storyboard.  To check, just right click (or ctrl click) on each element in a storyboard and note the connections.

My guess is if you look at that button in the storyboard, you will see "enterButoonOut" instead of "enterButtonOut"

Hope this helps!

Glenn

Comment: Everything in storyboard is spelled right but i did get this error after I changed it, but i am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Try this:  Bring up your storyboard with the screen where the button is.  Select the button by clicking on it until only the button is selected.  Once selected, either <Ctrl><Click> the button or <Right Click> the button (depending upon your mouse).  A menu will appear that shows all the links for that object.  My guess is there will be an additional link in the list with the mis-spelled value.  Next to the link, if you hover over the link, a "X" or "*" will appear.  Click that value to basically delete the link.  Let me know how that goes as I think that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled enterButoonOut and it must be enterButtonOut as per your declaration:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *enterButtonOut;
```